# Creating CSV file with current day mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, into-outfile

How can a export data from `mysql` to a file `csv` with the date and hour of the day. I try this code but I get a error

```
SELECT *
FROM order
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/',NOW(),'_orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

here my error

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"' ,NOW(), '"'_orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TER' at line 3
```

this is my event work great but im want diferent cvs in every end of the month

```
CREATE DEFINER = `admin`@`localhost` EVENT `Order` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY1 MONTH STARTS '2018-12-01 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
COMMENT 'Order save' 
DO SELECT *
FROM Order
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/_orders.csv'
```

Here the query getting the name with the date but I cant add this one in the event

```
SET @`outfull` := CONCAT('/tmp/', NOW(), 'orders.csv');
SET @`qry` := CONCAT('SELECT * 
                        INTO OUTFILE \'', @`outfull`, '\' 
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' 
                        ENCLOSED BY \'"\' 
                        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' 
                      FROM `order`');

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
SET @`qry` := NULL;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try prepared statement :

```
set @sql = concat('SELECT *
FROM tradooITLangues 
INTO OUTFILE ', concat('\'', '/tmp/', NOW(), '_orders.csv', '\''),
' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'
ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'#\n\';');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

In an event (my MySQL accepted the syntax) :

```
delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER = `admin`@`localhost` EVENT `Order` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2018-12-01 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
COMMENT 'Order save' 
DO
BEGIN

    SET @`outfull` := CONCAT('/tmp/', NOW(), 'orders.csv');
    SET @`qry` := CONCAT('SELECT * 
                            INTO OUTFILE \'', @`outfull`, '\' 
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' 
                            ENCLOSED BY \'"\' 
                            LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' 
                          FROM `order`');

    PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
    SET @`qry` := NULL;
    EXECUTE `stmt`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;

END;
$$
```

Comment: Yup, you can't even do `into outfile @outfile_path`. MySQL always manages to find new ways to horrify me.

Comment: I saw a query like that, but this query I want to put inside a `event` if I add that query and get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUnnZ.png

Comment: Please post entire `EVENT` command.
May be, your event can call a stored procedure?  This will allow a more complex command to be runned.

Comment: I put a complete example that combine `event` and `prepared statement` in my answer.

Comment: I went to query window in my phpmyadmin and I get this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8 ` line 8 it's `SET @`outfull``

Comment: I use MySQL Workbench and I don't have any syntax error.  The query run.  Which version of MySQL do you have?  If you run only line 8 on phpmyadmin, does it run?